# Default txt data import with too many delimiters with `fread` from `data.table`

Tags: r, regex, string, data.table, readr

I have a large set of data that I need to import. However, this base is a bit buggy in the raw files. The base has too many delimiters on some lines, due to data filling errors. I could correct in the raw base, but it is extremely long.

I would like to know if it is possible to correct this when importing `fread` from `data.table` or in another way.

For example, a snippet of data would look like this:

```
"Test File1"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File1"|2|3|8|"Baseline1"
"File test2"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|""|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File"|"o2"|2|3|8 |"Baseline2"
"Test File3"|"1"|"5"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File3"|2|3|8|"Baseline3"
"Test File4"|"1"|"5"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File4"|2|3|8|"Baseline"|"4 "
"Test File5"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File5"|2|3|8|"Baseline5"
"Test File5"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File5"|2|3|8|"Baseline5"
"File test6"|10|8|3|10|1|"6"|13|"File6"|2|10|13|"Baseline6"
"Test File7"|14|12|3|12|1|"6"|8|"File7"|2|7|6|"Baseline7"
"Test File8"|7|7|3|10|1|"6"|9|"File8"|2|11|14|"Baseline8"
"Test File9"|7|10|3|9|1|"6"|14|"File9"|2|11|14|"Baseline9"
"Test File10"|11|14|3|7|1|"6"|11|"File10"|2|6|11|"Baseline10"
"Test File11"|13|9|3|10|1|"6"|10|"File11"|2|10|13|"Baseline11"
"Test File12"|10|9|3|11|1|"6"|11|"File12"|2|6|8|"Baseline12"
"Test File13"|9|12|3|11|1|"6"|11|"File13"|2|11|6|"Baseline13"
"Test file14"|6|14|3|13|1|"6"|8|"File14"|2|11|6|"Baseline14"
"Test File15"|12|7|3|14|1|"6"|6|"File15"|2|6|12|"Baseline15"
"Trent" | "file16" | "1" |"5"| "3" |"4"| "5"| "6" | "2" | "Arch" | "" | "ivo16" |2|3|8| "Baseline" | "16"
"File test17"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File17"|2|3|8|"Ba"|"seline17 "
"Test File18"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|""|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File18"|2|3|8|"Baseline18"
```

However, I would like to get this structure:

```
"Test File1"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File1"|2|3|8|"Baseline1"
"File test2"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File2"|2|3|8|"Baseline2"
"Test File3"|"1"|"5"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File3"|2|3|8|"Baseline3"
"Test File4"|"1"|"5"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File4"|2|3|8|"Baseline4"
"Test File5"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File5"|2|3|8|"Baseline5"
"Test File5"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File5"|2|3|8|"Baseline5"
"File test6"|"10"|"8"|"3"|"10"|"1"|"6"|"13"|"File6"|2|10|13|"Baseline6"
"Test File7"|"14"|"12"|"3"|"12"|"1"|"6"|"8"|"File7"|2|7|6|"Baseline7"
"Test File8"|"7"|"7"|"3"|"10"|"1"|"6"|"9"|"File8"|2|11|14|"Baseline8"
"Test File9"|"7"|"10"|"3"|"9"|"1"|"6"|"14"|"File9"|2|11|14|"Baseline9"
"Test File10"|"11"|"14"|"3"|"7"|"1"|"6"|"11"|"File10"|2|6|11|"Baseline10"
"Test File11"|"13"|"9"|"3"|"10"|"1"|"6"|"10"|"File11"|2|10|13|"Baseline11"
"Test File12"|"10"|"9"|"3"|"11"|"1"|"6"|"11"|"File12"|2|6|8|"Baseline12"
"Test file13"|"9"|"12"|"3"|"11"|"1"|"6"|"11"|"File13"|2|11|6|"Baseline13"
"Test File14"|"6"|"14"|"3"|"13"|"1"|"6"|"8"|"File14"|2|11|6|"Baseline14"
"Test File15"|"12"|"7"|"3"|"14"|"1"|"6"|"6"|"File15"|2|6|12|"Baseline15"
"Trent file16"|"1"|"5"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File16"|2|3|8|"Baseline16"
"File test17"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File17"|2|3|8|"Baseline17"
"Test file18"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File18"|2|3|8|"Baseline18"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The changes look rather drastic, not only removing columns from line 16 but also merging columns in line 17. Do you have the ability to rerun the process that broke the process to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(stringr)

fn_Replace <- function(text)
{
  text <- stringr::str_remove_all(text, '\"|')
  text <- paste0('\"', text, '\"')
  return(text)
}

vec_Data <- c('"Test File1"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File1"|2|3|8|"Baseline1"',
              '"File test2"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|""|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File"|"o2"|2|3|8 |"Baseline2"',
              '"Test File3"|"1"|"5"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File3"|2|3|8|"Baseline3"',
              '"Test File4"|"1"|"5"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File4"|2|3|8|"Baseline"|"4 "',
              '"Test File5"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File5"|2|3|8|"Baseline5"',
              '"Test File5"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File5"|2|3|8|"Baseline5"',
              '"File test6"|10|8|3|10|1|"6"|13|"File6"|2|10|13|"Baseline6"',
              '"Test File7"|14|12|3|12|1|"6"|8|"File7"|2|7|6|"Baseline7"',
              '"Test File8"|7|7|3|10|1|"6"|9|"File8"|2|11|14|"Baseline8"',
              '"Test File9"|7|10|3|9|1|"6"|14|"File9"|2|11|14|"Baseline9"',
              '"Test File10"|11|14|3|7|1|"6"|11|"File10"|2|6|11|"Baseline10"',
              '"Test File11"|13|9|3|10|1|"6"|10|"File11"|2|10|13|"Baseline11"',
              '"Test File12"|10|9|3|11|1|"6"|11|"File12"|2|6|8|"Baseline12"',
              '"Test File13"|9|12|3|11|1|"6"|11|"File13"|2|11|6|"Baseline13"',
              '"Test file14"|6|14|3|13|1|"6"|8|"File14"|2|11|6|"Baseline14"',
              '"Test File15"|12|7|3|14|1|"6"|6|"File15"|2|6|12|"Baseline15"',
              '"Trent" | "file16" | "1" |"5"| "3" |"4"| "5"| "6" | "2" | "Arch" | "" | "ivo16" |2|3|8| "Baseline" | "16"',
              '"File test17"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File17"|2|3|8|"Ba"|"seline17 "',
              '"Test File18"|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|""|"5"|"6"|"2"|"File18"|2|3|8|"Baseline18"')

list_Data_Splitted <- stringr::str_split(vec_Data, "\\|")
list_Data_Splitted <- lapply(X = list_Data_Splitted , FUN = function(x){x[1 : 9] <- fn_Replace(x[1 : 9]); return(x)})
list_Data_Splitted <- lapply(X = list_Data_Splitted , FUN = function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "|"))
vec_Data_Splitted <- unlist(list_Data_Splitted)
vec_Data_Splitted

[1] "\"Test File1\"|\"1\"|\"2\"|\"3\"|\"4\"|\"5\"|\"6\"|\"2\"|\"File1\"|2|3|8|\"Baseline1\""                                               
 [2] "\"File test2\"|\"1\"|\"2\"|\"3\"|\"4\"|\"\"|\"5\"|\"6\"|\"2\"|\"File\"|\"o2\"|2|3|8 |\"Baseline2\""                                   
 [3] "\"Test File3\"|\"1\"|\"5\"|\"3\"|\"4\"|\"5\"|\"6\"|\"2\"|\"File3\"|2|3|8|\"Baseline3\""                                               
 [4] "\"Test File4\"|\"1\"|\"5\"|\"3\"|\"4\"|\"5\"|\"6\"|\"2\"|\"File4\"|2|3|8|\"Baseline\"|\"4 \""                                         
 [5] "\"Test File5\"|\"1\"|\"2\"|\"3\"|\"4\"|\"5\"|\"6\"|\"2\"|\"File5\"|2|3|8|\"Baseline5\""                                               
 [6] "\"Test File5\"|\"1\"|\"2\"|\"3\"|\"4\"|\"5\"|\"6\"|\"2\"|\"File5\"|2|3|8|\"Baseline5\""                                               
 [7] "\"File test6\"|\"10\"|\"8\"|\"3\"|\"10\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"13\"|\"File6\"|2|10|13|\"Baseline6\""                                          
 [8] "\"Test File7\"|\"14\"|\"12\"|\"3\"|\"12\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"8\"|\"File7\"|2|7|6|\"Baseline7\""                                            
 [9] "\"Test File8\"|\"7\"|\"7\"|\"3\"|\"10\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"9\"|\"File8\"|2|11|14|\"Baseline8\""                                            
[10] "\"Test File9\"|\"7\"|\"10\"|\"3\"|\"9\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"14\"|\"File9\"|2|11|14|\"Baseline9\""                                           
[11] "\"Test File10\"|\"11\"|\"14\"|\"3\"|\"7\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"11\"|\"File10\"|2|6|11|\"Baseline10\""                                        
[12] "\"Test File11\"|\"13\"|\"9\"|\"3\"|\"10\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"10\"|\"File11\"|2|10|13|\"Baseline11\""                                       
[13] "\"Test File12\"|\"10\"|\"9\"|\"3\"|\"11\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"11\"|\"File12\"|2|6|8|\"Baseline12\""                                         
[14] "\"Test File13\"|\"9\"|\"12\"|\"3\"|\"11\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"11\"|\"File13\"|2|11|6|\"Baseline13\""                                        
[15] "\"Test file14\"|\"6\"|\"14\"|\"3\"|\"13\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"8\"|\"File14\"|2|11|6|\"Baseline14\""                                         
[16] "\"Test File15\"|\"12\"|\"7\"|\"3\"|\"14\"|\"1\"|\"6\"|\"6\"|\"File15\"|2|6|12|\"Baseline15\""                                         
[17] "\"Trent \"|\" file16 \"|\" 1 \"|\"5\"|\" 3 \"|\"4\"|\" 5\"|\" 6 \"|\" 2 \"| \"Arch\" | \"\" | \"ivo16\" |2|3|8| \"Baseline\" | \"16\""
[18] "\"File test17\"|\"1\"|\"2\"|\"3\"|\"4\"|\"5\"|\"6\"|\"2\"|\"File17\"|2|3|8|\"Ba\"|\"seline17 \""                                      
[19] "\"Test File18\"|\"1\"|\"2\"|\"3\"|\"4\"|\"\"|\"5\"|\"6\"|\"2\"|\"File18\"|2|3|8|\"Baseline18\""
```